# Does Azure File Storage support basic authentication?

Tags: azure-storage

I have an **Azure File storage** folder and I would like to have a simple HTTP Basic User/Pass  authentication on it and be able to list the directory contents of that directory upon successful authentication.

I know that there are [Shared Access Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) but that's a different security approach.
This is so simple scenario but yet I cannot find a solution to it...

What I want to have is just a simple (bucket) folder that is going to be available over HTTP Basic Auth through the browser *externally*.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure File Storage support basic authentication?

At this time, Active Directory-based authentication and access control lists (ACLs) are not supported.

Azure Files supports [`identity-based authorization over SMB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-enable) (Server Message Block) through Azure Active Directory Domain Services. Your domain-joined Windows virtual machines (VMs) can access Azure file shares using Azure AD credentials.

Comment: I am not asking about AD authentication (which is actually supported as you wrote in the second sentence), ACLs will not help as well. I am asking about external public HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: It not support Basic Auth.